# Combining two lines into 1 in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, split, string-concatenation

An elderly family member recorded a memoir over the past few years, using Windows Notepad, so each file (by year) is simple text. I am tasked with normalizing the documents as much as possible, for a later print run. The problem I'm struggling with is how to handle each chapter title. Within a single text file could be multiple chapter entries. some chapter titles are very simple to get, for example:

```
Chapter 1
text
text
text.
chapter two
text
text
```

But she wasn't always so neat. Some of her documents contain lines like

```
"   chapter  
  three  
  "
```

with leading and trailing spaces and even a CarriageReturn/LineFeed between.

I cannot get the syntax to manage the "chapter three" situation. Here's what I have done so far:

```
$charstr = '   chapter    
    three
text here
more text 

    '
#remove leading spaces
$charstr2 = $charstr.trim() 
#find and replace chapter to all caps and start on a new line
$charstr2.Replace("chapter ",''nCHAPTER ')
```

I'd sure appreciate some assistance how to normalize that multi-line text string into a format like "CHAPTER three" (ideally, I will UPPER() the chapter
 number as well, like "CHAPTER THREE").

I've tried using \s, as in

> $charstr2 = $charstr.trim() -replace '\s+', 
>   but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Thanks!

read

Comment: You could either use regular expressions or wildcards. It's extremely easy to loop through each line and do a `*chapter*#*`. I'd also consider looking for 3rd party software to prettify the document and perhaps even convert it to a `.docx` format... I think powershell is not quite the best tool for this task

Comment: `(get-content -raw .\file.txt) -replace '(?m)^\s.chapter\s+(\w+)', "\`nCHAPTER \`$1"` - it's not clear whether you're working with a multiline string or an array of lines from `get-content`, but for a multiline string something like this regex might work.

Comment: should be `\s*` in my comment not `\s.`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - many thanks, your code got me started. I believe I have enough information to get this part of the memoir cleaned up.